# Mongoose Model - Including GridFS Image Reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, svg, gridfs

I'm trying to learn how to use GridFS (MongoDB), Mongoose, and Express. I am aiming to receive a `POST` with form data including SVG and JSON. I have the following model:

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
})
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

I am thinking that it would be expedient to use a [GridFS streaming library](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream). Here's what I *think* should happen:

```
//What to do here?
app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post;
    post.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files.image);//Can I do this?
    post.img.contentType = 'image/svg+xml';
    post.title = req.title;
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream([options]);
    fs.createReadStream('/some/path').pipe(writestream);
    post.save();
});
```

This is where I am very stuck. I need to read the image from the `POST` (I'm focusing on SVG for right now), connect it to my model somehow, and then have this model saved and the image saved to gridFS. Am I on the right track?

Comment: What you are defining here is not compatible to the general "GridFS" spec or the "gridfs-stream" library you are using. Unless you actually have "images" over 16MB then GridFS is likely not what you need. It is not the "file storage" API for MongoDB that people think it is. Read the manual. I think you really just want to store the data an retrieve it. MongoDB does this really well.

Comment: @NeilLunn, Thanks for the input. I am choosing GridFS because I can not confirm the size of my images. I need to start with SVG, so there might not be a problem for my starting task. Do you know where I can find information on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a better way to do this. The SVG images that I am using are all under 16MB (by a lot). SVG is just a string, so its actually pretty easy to serve. The important thing to remember is to also serve the proper content header (img/svg+xml).

**Mongoose.js Schema**

```
var svgPostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    img: { data: String, contentType: String }
})
```